# Authentication Failure when uploading to Azure Blob Storage using Azure.Storage.Blob v12.9.0

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I get this error when trying to upload files to blob storage. The error is present both when I run on localhost and when I run in Azure Function.

My connection string looks like:
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

*Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of the Authorization header.
Time:2021-10-14T15:56:26.7659660Z
Status: 400 (Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.)
ErrorCode: InvalidAuthenticationInfo*

But this used to work in the past but recently its started throwing this error for a new storage account I created. My code looks like below

```
    public AzureStorageService(IOptions<AzureStorageSettings> options)
    {
        _connectionString = options.Value.ConnectionString;
        _containerName = options.Value.ImageContainer;
        _sasCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(options.Value.AccountName, options.Value.Key);
        _blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString).Uri, _sasCredential);
        _containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_containerName);
    }
    public async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(IFormFile file, string location, bool publicAccess = true)
    {
        try
        {
            
            await _containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(publicAccess
                ? PublicAccessType.Blob
            : PublicAccessType.None);

            var blobClient = _containerClient.GetBlobClient(location);
            
            await using var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();

            // throws Exception here
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);

            return blobClient.Uri.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
    // To be able to do this, I have to create the container client via the blobService client which was created along with the SharedStorageKeyCredential
    public Uri GetSasContainerUri()
    {
        if (_containerClient.CanGenerateSasUri)
        {
            // Create a SAS token that's valid for one hour.
            var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = _containerClient.Name,
                Resource = "c"
            };

            sasBuilder.ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobContainerSasPermissions.Write);

            var sasUri = _containerClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
            Console.WriteLine("SAS URI for blob container is: {0}", sasUri);
            Console.WriteLine();

            return sasUri;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"BlobContainerClient must be authorized with Shared Key 
                      credentials to create a service SAS.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does your connection string look like? Please edit your question and include that. Please make sure to obfuscate account name and key before this information.

Comment: I faced the same issue few days ago... And instead of the usual connection string I had to provide a Shared Access Signature uri with the right authorizations as a connection string... Hope it works for you. I think azure enforced security on their storage accounts. (I also was using an Azure Function to upload files on a blob storage)

Comment: @Flo could you share me a sample of your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the following line of code:

```
_blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString).Uri, _sasCredential);
```

to

```
_blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString);
```

Considering your connection string has all the necessary information, you don't really need to do all the things you're doing and you will be using [`BlobServiceClient(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobServiceClient__ctor_System_String_) constructor which expects and accepts the connection string.

You can also delete the following line of code:

```
_sasCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(options.Value.AccountName, options.Value.Key);
```

and can probably get rid of `AccountName` and `Key` from your configuration settings if they are not used elsewhere.

Comment: I actually have another function that generates a SaSUrl for the container which the frontend app will use to upload larger files directly to the blob storage. To be able to generate a SaSUrl for the container I need to create the container client in the way I did

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your comment. Can you please edit your question and provide more details. Thanks.

Comment: I create the _containerClient in the way I do because I need to be able to generate a SaSUri for the container. To be able to do that, the container client must be created via blobService which is created with a StorageSharedKeyCredential

Comment: Understood. However if your connection string includes the credentials, then you don’t need to include it separately using StorageSharedKeyCredential.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!